# Capistrano 3 process failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm upgrading from Capistrano 2 to Capistrano 3 and everything seems to be running successfully except i'm seeing these 2 fail when it runs:

```
DEBUG [bbfe01ec] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /var/www/myapp/releases/20140211033611/public/assets ] on myapp.com
DEBUG [bbfe01ec] Command: [ -L /var/www/myapp/releases/20140211033611/public/assets ]
DEBUG [bbfe01ec] Finished in 0.146 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [26f99b11] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /var/www/myapp/releases/20140211033611/public/assets ] on myapp.com
DEBUG [26f99b11] Command: [ -d /var/www/myapp/releases/20140211033611/public/assets ]
DEBUG [26f99b11] Finished in 0.141 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

Why are these failing and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue and here is capistrano code, implementing when you receive these errors:

```
desc 'Symlink linked directories'
  task :linked_dirs do
    next unless any? :linked_dirs
    on release_roles :all do
      execute :mkdir, '-pv', linked_dir_parents(release_path)

      fetch(:linked_dirs).each do |dir|
        target = release_path.join(dir)
        source = shared_path.join(dir)
        unless test "[ -L #{target} ]"
          if test "[ -d #{target} ]"
            execute :rm, '-rf', target
          end
          execute :ln, '-s', source, target
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

As I can understand here is using command [ln](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_%28Unix%29) for creating symlinks.

Reading manual about ln (man ln) we understand, that the command will probably fail due to system restrictions, when trying to make hard link directories.

```
-d, -F, --directory
  allow the superuser to attempt to hard link directories (note: will probably fail 
  due to system restrictions, even for the superuser)
```

'ln -d' failing to create hard link and that's why executing 'ln -s' in order to create symlink(symbolic link instead of hard link).

So, no worries about this fail. If you would like to avoid it just change your deploy options like this:

```
set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :info
```

Comment: So how did you know that `/usr/bin/env [ -L /var/www/myapp/releases/20140211033611/public/assets ]` is trying to create a link? I've used `ln` before in linux, but did not know what this command was even trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, I have the same error as you and just go through capistrano code with 'deploy flow' in mind (http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/flow/). It helps me to make out where this fail occurs